# Are there any risks involved in Hosting your website on free webhosts?

Tags: web-hosting, security

I am planning to host my collage project web site on any such free webhost, is it secure or are there any **disadvantages** or **risks** or security issues that i may experience if i go for **free web-hosting**?

any inputs are appreciated!

Comment: This is more of an alternative to the actual question, so I'll add as a comment. A Small Orange has a Tiny plan that's only $25/year which you might consider as a better option than taking your chances with a free host. Other than limited space and bandwidth(compared to their regular plans; it's still not bad), it's a full-fledged hosting account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there could be many disadvantages such as:

- Lack of Support
- Low performance by servers compared to others
- Lot of Advertising
- Hidden Charges
- Unreliable
- Poor web security